# How to make javascript that'll click automatically inside iframe's link?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible ?

I've made on page with iframe, I want a script that'll click automatically inside in one iframe's link.

But I also want that script to detect half link, I mean the link which is in iframe changes everytime, but the first part of the link doesnt change, so the javascript should detect half link which doesnt change and redirect to it...

Comment: Only possible if the iframes content is on the same domain. Is it on the same domain?

Comment: ... i think is useless method ... do a redirect with `window.location` to the page of the `iframe`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write a "client" library and import it within iFrame. This library listen to a message from HTML5 postMessage call with certain attribute and react appropriately. Since you have access to the parent object through the event object (or window.parent), you can also send response back with the result. This way, it doesn't matter if it's cross-domain and as long as this library exists, you can communicate back-and-forth and even has the iFrame initiate if you write it properly.

I can't share the code with you since it's our proprietary library, but that's part of the idea.

Comment: Of course, this relies on you being able to change both the parent page and the iFrame page.

Comment: Yup, you shouldn't be able to randomly alter something on another domain for security reason. It seems to me that the person who asked the question has control of both.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your iframe is from a different domain, you can't. Allowing this would be a major security concern.

If your iframe content is in the same domain, then you can access the iframe content through its [contentWindow property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctglqj.php). You can then work with your iframe link the same way you would if the link was in the main page.